# Regex Java Endpoint Annotations

Tags: java, javascript, python, regex, perl

I have a project to document all the endpoints in a really big project. I only have the source files, so I can't run some sort of documentation tool on it. My only resource (as far as I know) is regex with perl or python or something like that.

Here's an example of the annotations on a method:

```
/**
 * Method Javadoc
 */
@Endpoint
@POST
@Path("path/{objectid}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@TypeHint(SomeObject.class)
public Response deleteObject(@PathParam("objectid") Integer objectid) {
  //method code
}
```

The only thing that I believe I can trust is consistant is that every endpoint method will have the `@Endpoint` annotation on it. It may or may not be the first annotation. The methods can have any signature.

Any help with the regex for something like this would be great. I expect that it will take a bit more than just a regex to match all of this information, so some [python](/questions/tagged/python), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), or even [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) would be helpful too!

Just so you know what I'm going for (I don't expect you to do the work for me, I'm mostly looking for help with the regex), what I want out of this is a csv with the following construct:

```
SourceFile.java  |  MethodName  |      Path       | Method  |  QueryParams  |  FormParams  |  Consumes                  |  Produces                                                |  ReturnedObject
ClassName.java   | deleteObject | path/{objectid} |  POST   |  objectid,    |              | MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON |  {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML} | SomeObject.class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how set are you on regexp being your only solution?
assumming you have the code compiled (or can compile it), and that the annotatio(s) your after is retailed, you could write a java method that goes over all classes, loads them using class.forName() and then you have a wide variety of reflection APIs at your disposal to inspect annotations on classes, methods, fields etc.

if the classes are jarred up you simply add the jar to your classpath when running, then open it using a ZipInputStream, go over the entries, and load them one by one using class.forName(). if its "exploded" (just a bunch of *.class files) your job is even easier.

going over a zip (which *.jar, *.ear, *.war are) goes something like:

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("fileName"));
ZipEntry entry;
while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry())!=null) {
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
        continue;
    }
    if (!entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
        continue;
    }
    Class theClass = Class.forName(entry.getName());
    Endpoint targetAnnotation = theClass.getAnnotation(Endpoint.class);
    if (targetAnnotation == null) {
        continue;
    }
    //probably what youre looking for
}
```

of course, you program needs to be executed with the target *.war/jar/ear on the lasspath of the execution for the `Class.forName()` call to work. if the compiled code isnt jarred up then you can simply trverse the file system in a very similar way.

if the annotations youre after are not retained post-compilation you might consider bringin in a library that can read java code and walk the syntax tree, for example [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html#sec-parsing-a-source-file)

Comment: I may be able to get a hold of a `*.war` file that would make this possible. I've used `reflection` before to do something similar to this, but I'm not familiar with `ZipInputStream` or how a bunch of `*.class` files would make my job easier. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @kentcdodds - i've expanded my answer with mock code and another alternative

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm getting a ClassNotFound on that `Class.forName()`. And I have the `*.war` file on my classpath. I'm not sure what's wrong with it...

Comment: @kentcdodds - wars/ears might have a more complex structure that would prevent the java classloader from properly seeig their contents. maybe your *.war contains further *.jars under /lib or something inside? if so you will need to extract all of them and process them (put all on the classpath and go over all of their contents)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work in Perl, e.g.,

```
my $found_method;
my $found_endpoint;

# Iterate over each line of the input .java file
while (<>) {
  $found_method = 0;
  $found_endpoint = 0;

  # Look for an @endpoint annotation, and capture what's between the
  # parenthesees.  Do the same for each annotation.
  if (/\@endpoint/i) {
    $found_endpoint = 1;
  } elsif (/\@path\(([^\)]+)\)/i) {
    $path = $+;
  } elsif (/\@consumes\(([^\)]+)\)/i) {
    $consumes = $+;
  } elsif (/\@produces\(([^\)]+)\)/i) {
    $produces = $+;
  } elsif (/\@typehint\(([^\)]+)\)/i) {
    $typehint = $+;

  # Look for a method definition (all on one line)
  } elsif (/\w+\s+\w+\(.*{/i) {
    $open_brackets = 1;

    # Skip over the bracketed method definition
    while ($open_brackets) {
      $found_method = 1;
      if (/{/) {
        $open_brackets++;
      } elsif (/{/) {
        $open_brackets--;
      }
    }
  }

  # If we just finished passing over an annotated method, output what we
  # found
  if ($found_method and  $found_endpoint) {
    print "\npath = " . $path;
    print "\nconsumes = " . $consumes;
    print "\nproduces = " . $produces;
    print "\ntypehint = " . $typehint;
  }
}
```